# Is there an alternative to google maps' toScreenLocation?

Tags: android, performance, google-maps

I have to draw lots of stuff over a map every frame (because of the Mercator projection any movement of the map needs a recalculation of the coordinates.)

In maps api v1 `Projection.toPixels(GeoPoint arg0, Point arg1)` was quite fast because it didn't create a new Point object for every call and was faster generally.

In maps api v2 `Projection.toScreenLocation(LatLng location)` returns a new Point object for every call which leads to massive GC delays (100ms every other sec) and somehow it's about 10 times slower than the v1 version.

Right now I have framerates below 10 fps so i need to change something. I could draw things onto Tiles but that would create a lot of overhead because of what i have to draw etc.

The best would be some alternative or manual calculation but i am not sure how to replace Googles `Projection` and i cannot look at the sources because Maps isn't public.

The only answer to this question [Google Maps v2 Projection.toScreenLocation(...) extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26215787/1092271) is NOT good as the things i draw are recalculated at runtime.

Comment: try this library https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I have asked a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850292/google-maps-projection-algorithm and I just found your's here